# How to handle non-English IME keyboard inputs in GLFW?

Tags: java, glfw, ime

For example, I'm using Chinese IME. When I press a key, GLFW would not receive it. Instead, it popped up a small window displaying what character I typed.
I want that when I press a key in Chinese IME, the small window wouldn't appear and I can send the key (maybe translate it to a character) to GLFW.

I've seen a [project](https://github.com/Windmill-City/IngameIME-Minecraft) which fulfill it in Minecraft. I want to know how it works and implement it in my Java/OpenGL program.
Here is the picture of the small window(I don't want it).
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfudm.png)